Need to fix time zone issue for my Python, Pyspark processing job
I have database column in Postgres aurora “last_updated_timestamp” which is without timezone and has value “2024-08-01 00:00:00”
I am fetching that value using pyspark df when I do df.show()
It is showing same value :
2024-08-01 00:00:00.
For my use case, I have a function write_df_to_delta_table() which writes this df to AWS S3 data lake in the form of delta table which is in parquet format.
When I download this parquet file and view it using Avro and Parquet viewer plugin in Pycharm, it is showing as
2024-07-31T18:30:00Z[UTC]
For my use case, I want it to show as
2024-08-01 00:00:00[PST].
I don’t want to change conf of my spark session as it may affect other processes I have.
I tried implementing below code:
df = df.withColumn( "updated_timestamp_pst",  from_utc_timestamp(col("updated_timestamp"), "PST") )
But now it is showing as:
2024-08-01T00:00:00Z[UTC]
which is not acceptable.
I want it only in PST but with same timestamp value.


Convert to a string in PST timezone:
First convert it in a string then concatenate it with timezone you want.

Using the date_format function, you can ensure the timestamp remains
unchanged but gets the desired timezone tag for presentation.
df = df.withColumn(
    "updated_timestamp_pst", 
    concat(
        date_format("last_updated_timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), 
        lit("[PST]")
    )




The issue arises because the from_utc_timestamp function assumes that the input timestamp is in UTC and then converts it to the specified timezone. However since you know the timezone is PST, you can create col _pst to specify PST time zone.
sdf = sdf.withColumn(
    "updated_timestamp_pst", 
    to_timestamp(col("updated_timestamp"))
)

sdf = sdf.withColumn(
    "updated_timestamp_pst", 
    col("updated_timestamp_pst").cast("string") + lit("[PST]")
)

